Python - Separar numero en trozos
Necesito separar un numero en sus cifras, por ejemplo, si tengo el numero 27389, quiero utilizar split() para separarlo y que dé como resultado 2 7 3 8 9, pero al intentarlo de esa manera me da el error ValueError: empty separator, ademas, si es posible me gustaria poder separar en la cantidad de cifras que quiera, ya sea de 1 en 1, de 2 en 2, de 3 en 3, etcétera. Y por mas que intento usar el split(), no me funciona. Si alguien fuera tan amable de orientarme lo agradecería, a continuación dejo mi codigo:
A=input("Ingrese tres numeros: ") #AQUI METO LA CADENA DE NUMEROS QUE VOY A SEPARAR
print(A)
number=list(map(int, A.split(""))) #SE SUPONE QUE EN ESTA LINEA ES DONDE SE SEPARA LA CADENA DE NUMEROS EN SUS CIFRAS
print(number)


str.split() necesita una cadena con un carácter o más como separador, que usara para partir la cadena. Si sep no se especifica (None por defecto), separa usando espacios en blanco. str.split te seria útil si tus dígitos/números estuvieran separados por espacios, comas, etc, pero no para partir una cadena sin usar un separador.
Para obtener cada dígito como un entero es mucho mas simple, solo pasale a map() la cadena directamente:
>>> a = "27389"
>>> numbers = list(map(int, a))
>>> numbers
[2, 7, 3, 8, 9]

map() aplica la función a cada item del segundo argumento, que puede ser cualquier iterable. En el caso de las cadenas se itera carácter a carácter.
También podrías usar un simple for, por ejemplo mediante una lista por compresión:
>>> numbers = [int(digito) for digito in a]
>>> numbers
[2, 7, 3, 8, 9]

En general, para dividir cualquier cadena en caracteres individuales basta con pasarsela a list() o tuple():
>>> list(a)
['2', '7', '3', '8', '9']

Si quieres dividir la cadena cada n caracteres, creo que textwrap.wrap() se ajusta exactamente a lo que necesitas en tu caso concreto:
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> a = "27389"

>>> wrap(a, 1)
['2', '7', '3', '8', '9']
>>> wrap(a, 2)
['27', '38', '9']
>>> wrap(a, 3)
['273', '89']
>>> wrap(a, 4)
['2738', '9']
>>> wrap(a, 5)
['27389']

>>> numbers = list(map(int, wrap(a, 2)))
>>> numbers
[27, 38, 9]


Nota: textwrap.wrap() no se limita a partir la cadena en fragmentos, en este caso solo hace eso, pero si la cadena tiene espacios, caracteres de nueva linea, guiones, etc el resultado puede no ser el esperado.

Otra formas típica de hacer esto es simplemente mediante rebanado de cadenas:
>>> numbers = [int(a[idx:idx+2]) for idx in range(0, len(a), 2)]
>>> numbers
[27, 38, 9]


Edición
Como comenta @JorgeLuis, en Python 3.12 se ha añadido la función itertools.batched() que junto a str.join() permite también resolver el problema de manera bastante eficiente:
>>> numbers = [int("".join(batch)) for batch in batched(a, 2)]
>>> numbers
[27, 38, 9]

o si prefieres una aproximación funcional:
>>> numbers = list(map(int, map("".join, batched(a, 2))))
>>> numbers
[27, 38, 9]


Recomiendo echar un ojo a la función introducida en Python 3.12  itertools.batched.

@JorgeLuis muy buena sugerencia, lo he agregado a la respuesta. La verdad es que se me había olvidado por completo, aún vivo mayormente en Python < 3.11 a la espera que algunas librerías terminen de portarse... Gracias por sugerirlo, saludos.

Solución con comprensión de listas:
a = "12324"
b = [int(x) for x in a]

El for itera sobre el string a. Cada letra es pasada por int() y el valor agregado a la lista b.
Para dividir en trozos de un tamano arbitrario, puedes definir una función partir, que es la misma expresión anterior, pero indicando subrangos del string.
def partir(valor, tamano):
    return [int(valor[i:i+tamano]) for i in range(0, len(valor), tamano)]

Demo
a = "12324"
b = [int(x) for x in a]
print(b)

def partir(valor, tamano):
    return [int(valor[i:i+tamano]) for i in range(0, len(valor), tamano)]

print(partir(a, 2))
print(partir(a, 3))

produce:
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
[12, 32, 4]
[123, 24]

Process finished with exit code 0


Usando expresiones regulares:
def partir(valor, tamano):
    patron = "(\\d{1," + str(tamano) + "})"
    return [int(x) for x in re.findall(patron, valor)]

Se usa un patrón de captura del tipo (\d{1,n}), que captura una secuencia de dígitos de largo 1 a n.
Demo
import re

def partir(valor, tamano):
    patron = "(\\d{1," + str(tamano) + "})"
    return [int(x) for x in re.findall(patron, valor)]

a = "12324"
for i in range(1, 7):
    print(i, partir(a, i))

produce:
1 [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
2 [12, 32, 4]
3 [123, 24]
4 [1232, 4]
5 [12324]
6 [12324]

Process finished with exit code 0

